# Prevent form resubmit after Browser Back button click

Tags: browsers, forms

In the early days of the web it was a problem that clicking the browser's `Back` button after clicking `Submit` could cause the form to be resubmitted so one might, for instance, end up with a double purchase.

This does not seem to be a problem any longer. How was it fixed? Do individual sites have to work around this or did browsers change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to prevent this is to use the [**POST/Redirect/GET** pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Instead of directly sending a `200` after receiving the POST request, the server sends a `303` (or `302`) redirect instead. The client follows it and gets (via GET) a `200` then. Refreshing this page repeats the last GET, not the previous POST.

For implementation questions, see the Stack Overflow tag "[post-redirect-get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post-redirect-get)".

Comment: And in regards to the direct question, when you press Back in the browser you go back to the initial page, not the intermediate POST request.

Comment: one reason why people don't use the *post-redirect-get* pattern is to avoid the need for the user to fill the same form again in case something fails in the form submission. AFAIK, Ajax form submits cannot follow the post-redirect-get pattern

Comment: It's not the answer to original question. PRG stands for the case with page refresh, not Back previous page

Answer (score 0):

I've used a javascript POST of the form data followed by a js re-direct.  Using the back button doesn't cause those forums to be re-submitted.